# Mongoose $group & $lookup aggregation returns empty array with $unwind

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 schemas TravelRoute & Flights. I am trying to find the $min of Flight.fare.total_price and return that result with some details from TravelRoute which is ref-ed in the Flights schema. I am using Mongo 3.4.1 and Mongoose 4.8.5

```
const TravelRoute = new mongoose.Schema({
    departureAirport: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
    },
    arrivalAirport: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
    },
    durationDays: {
        type: Number
    },
    fromNow: {
        type: Number
    },
    isActive: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    class: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['economy', 'business', 'first', 'any']
    }
}

const Flights = new mongoose.Schema({
    route: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'TravelRoute'
    },
    departure_date: {
        type: Date
    },
    return_date: {
        type: Date
    },
    fare: {
        total_price: {
            type: Number
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following code:

```
Flights.aggregate(
        {$group: {
                _id: {
                    route: '$route',
                    departure_date: '$departure_date',
                    return_date: '$return_date'
                },
                total_price: {$min: '$fare.total_price'}
            }
        },
        {$lookup: {
            from: 'TravelRoute',
            localField: '_id.route',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'routes'
        }},
        {$unwind: '$routes'},
        {$project: {
            'routes.departureAirport': 1,
            'routes.destinationAirport': 1,
            'departure_date': 1,
            'return_date': 1,
            'total_price': 1,
            '_id': 1
        }},
        {$sort: {'total_price': 1}},
        function(err, cheapFlights){
            if (err) {
                log.error(err)
                return next(new errors.InvalidContentError(err.errors.name.message))
            }
            res.send(cheapFlights)
            next()
        })
```

The above returns an empty array [] when I use $unwind. When I comment out the $unwind stage, it returns the following:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "route": "58b30cac0efb1c7ebcd14e0a",
      "departure_date": "2017-04-03T00:00:00.000Z",
      "return_date": "2017-04-08T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "total_price": 385.6,
    "routes": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "route": "58ae47ddc30b175150d94eef",
      "departure_date": "2017-04-03T00:00:00.000Z",
      "return_date": "2017-04-10T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "total_price": 823.68,
    "routes": []
  } 
...
```

I'm reasonably new to Mongo and Mongoose. I am confounded by the the fact that it returns "routes" even though I don't project that. And it doesn't return departure_date (etc) even though I ask for it? I am not sure I need $unwind as there will only be one TravelRoute per Flight.

Thanks...

**Edit**

Here was the final solution:

```
  {$lookup: {
            from: 'travelroutes', //<-- this is the collection name in the DB
            localField: '_id.route',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'routes'
        }},
        {$unwind: '$routes'},
        {$project: {
            departureAirport: '$routes.departureAirport',
            arrivalAirport: '$routes.arrivalAirport',
            departureDate: '$_id.departure_date',
            returnDate: '$_id.return_date',
            'total_price': 1,
            'routeID': '$_id.route',
            '_id': 0
        }},
        {$sort: {'total_price': 1}},
```

Comment: If I remember correctly you have to use collection name instead of schemas name in lookup's `from` attribute.

Comment: Yea, that was it. Wow, thanks!

Do you know how I can get "departure_date" if I don't $project the _id?

Comment: Np. You can use the departure_date: "$_id.departure_date" in project stage

Comment: @slippedon you should post the solution as answer and accept it yourself, it will be more complete reference for future help seeker i think.